# Optimzation of nested for loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, cosine-similarity

x_tsvd is matrix of length 4.6 million(row).
svd_tfidf is matrix of length 1862(row).

Both matrix has same number of column(260).

And i wand to calcuate cosine similarity for each 4.6 M rows of x_tsvd for each 1862 svd_tfidf.

Is there any way i can optimize it so that it take less time.

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
best_match=[]

keys=np.array(df_5M['file'])
values=np.array(df['file'])

for i in range(len(x_tsvd)):
    array_=[]
    for j in range (len(svd_tfidf)):
        cosine_similarity_=np.dot(x_tsvd[i],svd_tfidf[j])/(norm(x_tsvd[i])*norm(svd_tfidf[j]))
        array_.append(cosine_similarity_)
    index=np.array(array_).argsort()
    best_match.append({keys[i]:values[index][::-1][0:5]})
```

Update:

````
from numpy.linalg import norm
best_match=[]
#b=copy.copy(svd_tfidf)
keys=np.array(df_5M['file'])
values=np.array(df['file'])
#b=copy.copy(svd_tfidf)
for i in range(len(x_tsvd)):
    a=x_tsvd[i]
    b=svd_tfidf
    a_dot_b=np.sum(np.multiply(a,b),axis=1)
    norm_a=norm(a)
    norm_b=norm(b,axis=1)
    cosine_similarity_=a_dot_b/(norm_a*norm_b)
    index=np.argsort(cosine_similarity_)
    best_match.append({keys[i]:values[index][::-1][0:6]})       
        
     ```
````

Comment: replace range(len(ARR) with enumerate(ARR). instead of i you'll get a tuple of (i,element). replace array indexing for each with that element instead. Should slightly increase efficiency, but if you want to compare each element of one array against all elements of another, it'll take time regardless

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code. First of all, `norm(x_tsvd[i])` is **recomputed** `len(svd_tfidf)=1862` times while the expression can be move in the parent loop. Furthermore, `norm(svd_tfidf[j])` is recomputed `len(x_tsvd)=4.6e6` times while the expression can be **precomputed** for all `j` values only once. Moreover, calling `np.dot(x_tsvd[i],svd_tfidf[j])` in two nested loops is not efficient. You can use a big **matrix multiplication**: `x_tsvd @ svd_tfidf.T`. However, since this matrix is huge (~64 GiB), it is reasonable to split `x_tsvd` in **chunks** of size 512~4096. Additionally, you can precompute the inverse of the norm because the multiplication by the **inverse** value is generally significantly faster than divisions. `np.argsort(tmp_matrix[i])[::-1][0:5]]` is not efficient and **`argpartition`** can be used instead to only compute the 5 best items (as I pointed out in a comment of the previous answer which advised you to use `argsort`). Note that a partition does not behave the same way than a sort if you care about equal items (ie. stable sort). There are no stable partitioning implementation available yet in Numpy.

In the end the optimized implementation should look like:

```
inv_norm_j = 1.0 / norm_by_line(svd_tfidf) # Horizontal vector

for chunk_start in range(0, len(x_tsvd), chunk_size):
    chunk_end = min(chunk_start + chunk_size, len(x_tsvd))
    inv_norm_i = 1.0 / norm_by_line(x_tsvd_block)[:,None] # Vertical vector
    x_tsvd_block = x_tsvd[chunk_start:chunk_end]
    tmp_matrix = (x_tsvd_block @ svd_tfidf.T) * inv_norm_i * inv_norm_j
    best_match_values = values[np.sort(np.argpartition(tmp_matrix, len(svd_tfidf)-5)[:,-5:])[:,::-1]]
    # Pure-Python part that can hardly be optimized
    for i in range(chunk_start, chunk_end):
        best_match.append({keys[i]: best_match_values[i]})
```

Where `norm_by_line` can be computed in a vectorized way (certainly with Scipy for example). Note that this is a untested draft and not a code that you should trust completely and copy-part blindly ;) .

---

Regarding the recent update (which is a code computing a different result), most optimizations are identical but there is a big improvement you can do on `np.sum(np.multiply(a,b),axis=1)`. Indeed, you can use `np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)` instead so not to compute the large expensive temporary matrix. It is 3 times faster on my machine.

Comment: Richard i have written another code.Could you please hepl me to optimize it. ` from numpy.linalg import norm
best_match=[]
#b=copy.copy(svd_tfidf)
keys=np.array(df_5M['file'])
values=np.array(df['file'])
#b=copy.copy(svd_tfidf)
for i in range(len(x_tsvd)):
    a=x_tsvd[i]
    b=svd_tfidf
    a_dot_b=np.sum(np.multiply(a,b),axis=1)
    norm_a=norm(a)
    norm_b=norm(b,axis=1)
    cosine_similarity_=a_dot_b/(norm_a*norm_b)
    index=np.argsort(cosine_similarity_)
    best_match.append({keys[i]:values[index][::-1][0:6]})       
   `

Comment: Can you post the code as an update? This one is far from being easy to read.